# git error on all repositories, pre-existing and brand new (error: bad index file sha1 signature fatal: index file corrupt)

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04, corrupt

I have a problem where if a try to commit changes on any git repository I get the error:

error: bad index file sha1 signature

fatal: index file corrupt

This happens on any repo I try, both existing repos that previously worked fine and brand new ones created for the purpose of trying to find out what is going on.

The only time the error is not generated is if I commit an empty repository.

I have tried:

rm -f .git/index

git reset

as suggested in many posts but this  has no effect.

I am running git in a virtual machine (Ubuntu 16.04.3).

When running git on the the host OS (macOS Sierra 10.12.6) there is no problem. I can use git as normal.

Any suggestions for what I can do in order to be able commit from within the Ubuntu VM again would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to control the VM and where did you place the virtual drive (i.e., is it shared with something)?

Comment: Thanks torek, I'm controlling the VM using VMWare Fusion. The virtual drive is shared with the host OS.

Comment: Curious. There's only one place that actually checks this and prints that error message, and that only happens if you run `git fsck`. In general index sharing *should* (mostly?) work as long as your Git is at least 1.7.11, when index format v4 was introduced. If the `.git` directory gets touched by something like Dropbox, though, that could wreck everything (Dropbox thinks it's smarter than Git).